# How to stop Delphi from generating a RSM file?

Tags: delphi, compilation, 64-bit, delphi-xe7, rsm

I just added the '64 bits platform' to my project and my Delphi (XE7) keeps generating a huge RSM file (which increases the compilation time). According to the [Help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/RSM_Debug_File) this should not happen if the 'Include remote debug symbols' option is disabled.

And in my case it is disabled.
[image]
There is something else to be disabled?

Comment: Can anybody confirm that the RSM file is generated no matter what, on their machine? (when compiling for 64 bit, of course)

Comment: 5 years late but yes: using delphi 10.4.2 the rsm file is generated regardless of the setting of that flag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.ide/201203/12030416462.html

> Delphi XE2 generates RSM files that are several MB in size.  As I
>   understand it, these files are for remote debugging.  Is there a way
>   to turn off the generation of these files?
>
> Yes. In the Project Options look on the page "Delphi Compiler\Linking"
>   for "Include remote debug symbols" and turn it off if you do Win32
>   debugging. Note it is necessary for Win64 debugging.

and continuing on http://www.devsuperpage.com/search/Articles.aspx?G=2&ArtID=20168

> The IDE is 32-bit, because that's the only way it can work on both 32
>   and 64 bit versions of Windows. (Win64 can run 32 bit apps, but Win32
>   can't run 64 bit apps.) That's why the remote debugger is used for 64
>   bit and cross-platform apps.

Jeff Overcash from TeamB

> Is the reason that Delphi XE2 is not itself really 64-bit?
>
> Sure, then it can't be run on 32 bit OS's.  All third party components
>   won't  work at all until a 64 bit version of it exists (a 64 bit IDE
>   would not be able  to load a 32 bit bpl), this would be a major reason
>   for people not to upgrade  too.  Supporting both a 32 bit and 64 bit
>   IDE doubles the testing time for  little to no benefit.

Comment: I don't know about that.... Why Embarcadero would let the used disabled that option if it is mandatory on 64 bit platforms?

Comment: I've updated the answer. It is illogical, but I believe only the guys from Embt can give a more accurate and in-depth answer.

Comment: I would not call it a bug. The option is just missing a note that it is only valid for Win32. There are other options that are only valid for specific targets, which usually is mentioned in the wording. This option just misses that.

Comment: I follow @UweRaabe in the fact that is is not directly a bug, but it seems to be a requirement to cross-compile and remote-debug a Win64 executable from a Win32 process. In fact, this may be overridden by running the debug process within the Win64 compiled process at low-level, but it sounds not worth it. A separated .rsm file is a fine workaround, and I would rather see Embarcadero focus on other thinks (like Linux support, or fix the Error Insight compiler) instead of getting rid of this .rsm file. Of course, debugging experience is worse on Win64 than Win32... but it works in most cases...

Comment: "is just missing a note that it is only valid for Win32" - you know that famous quote: "it's not a bug! it's an undocumented feature" :) :) :)   Technically it is a bug. A check box that is not doing what it was supposed to do (and the behavior is not documented) ... that's a (small) bug. Just enough to create a StackOverflow discussion :)