# Delphi keeps generating .RSM files for 64 bit

Tags: delphi, linker, delphi-11-alexandria

I have this weird situation where my 64bit compiles generate .RSM files.
The linker setting for 'Include remote debug settings' is false, but it is boldfaced:

[image]

Playing with this setting, I found out that it seems to be associated with `<DCC_RemoteDebug>true</DCC_RemoteDebug>` in the .dproj files.
I even removed some of these lines from .dproj files while the IDE was closed.

This is Delphi Alexandria 11.3.1

How can I fix this?
Where do I change 'Value from debug configuration - All platforms'?

Comment: All 64 bit Delphi debugging is considered remote including on the same machine. At least until the Delphi IDE itself goes 64 bit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182442/how-to-stop-delphi-from-generating-a-rsm-file

Comment: Marking my own question as a dupe. Is that a badge? ;-)